# a special case when modifing the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

sometimes i face the following case in my database design,, i wanna to know what is the best practice to handle this case:::

for example i have a specific table and after a while ,, when the database in operation and some real data are already entered.. i need to add some required fields (that supposed not to accept null)..

what is the best practice in this situation..

make the field accept null as (some data already entered in the table ,, and scarify the important constraint )and try to force the user to enter this field through some validation in the code..

truncate all the entered data and reentered them again (tedious work)..

any other suggestions about this issue...

Comment: Truncating the table and re-entry is not required !?!?!

Comment: thanks so much ,, i just write the scenarios in my head now ,, if there are more suggestions , this will be great ,, i just wanna to know the best practice in this case to be professional ,and not to break any rule or constrains of data base design...

Comment: @user418343. Ok. Note my comments on dportas' and kevchadders' answers.  No use me repeting what other have already stated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to go about it is to truncate the data and re - enter it again, but it need not be too tedious an item. Temporary tables and table variables could assist a great deal with this issue. A simple procedure comes to mind to go about it:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, Right - click on the table you wish to modify and select `Script Table As` > `CREATE To` > `New Query Editor Window`.
2. Add a `#` in front of the table name in the `CREATE` statement.
3. Move all records into the temporary table, using something to the effect of:

   `INSERT INTO #temp SELECT * FROM original`
4. Then run the script to keep all your records into the temporary table.
5. Truncate your original table, and make any changes necessary.
6. Right - click on the table and select `Script Table As` > `INSERT To` > `Clipboard`, paste it into your query editor window and modify it to read records from the temporary table, using `INSERT .. SELECT`.

That's it. Admittedly not quite straightforward, but a well - kept database is almost always worth a slight hassle.

Comment: @Ioannis: I'm curious as to why you would prefer to go to so much trouble. Why not just create the new column and then populate it? Truncating the entire table seems unnecessary and drastic. It would mean that the database (or at least this table) had to be out of use for a much longer period of time for no obvious benefit.

Comment: I would not. I think that NOT NULL fields don't make much sense in most scenarios. Instead, defaults offer more flexibility. However, there are some cases where they do, ergo the steps above.

Comment: @Ioannis: 1. Totally un-scalable.  2. Truncate & r-entry is completely hilarious and unnecessary.  3. You have not answered the basic question, which is *for the existing rows, what to load into the new column ?*

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: 
1. Please explain. 
2. As I mentioned, not something to do every day but useful nonetheless. Characterizing something as 'hilarious' is NOT constructive, unless when dealing with comedy. 
3. This is NOT the basic question. It's a question that 's explained by the person responsible for the decision to make the field unable to accept `null`, which should obviously fill in the blanks here.

Comment: You do not need to go through these steps to create a non-null column and I would not advise it. "I think that NOT NULL fields don't make much sense in most scenarios." Oh boy! I think there must be some big caveats and explanations that you left out of that sentence.

Comment: @Ioannis: *Please explain*. Sure, post a question. *Comedy*: your answer is comedy.  Are you seriously going to tell the users to re-enter data, when you can copy the table and preserve that data using SQL commands.  This is 2010, right, for profesional programmers, right, using SQL, right.  Check the other answers.  Delete your answer before you embarrass yourself further.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: If you think demeaning remarks and aggressiveness are considered professional in any capacity, you are sadly mistaken. Next time, instead of criticizing, you could try to provide an answer of some kind. That way, other people might actually benefit from it.

Comment: @Ioannis: There is no need to add yet another answer stating what other answers already. I have already commented and voted on the right answers.  that's how it is done here. Without repeating and re-entering and truncating. After all, it is a computer system.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on requirements. If the data to populate existing rows for the new column isn't available immediately then I would generally prefer to create a new table and just populate new rows when the data exists. If and when you have all the data for every row then put the new column into the original table.

Comment: This is the only correct, "best practice" answer.  To be clear, the new table will have only two columns: the PK of the old table; and the new column. The relation is 1::0-1.

Answer (score 1):

If possible i would set a default value for the new column.

e.g. For Varchar

```
alter table table_name 
    add column_name varchar(10) not null 
    constraint column_name_default default ('Test')
```

After you have updated you could then drop the default

```
alter table table_name 
drop constraint column_name_default
```

A lot will come down to your requirements.

Comment: 1. The answer is correct in intent, the second best method.  It retains the single table, and loads a known value into the new column for the existing rows (which do not have a value).  2. Please change "DF_Default_Object_Name" to "column_name_default".  3. The Edit is wrong: you have to recreate the table (via Alter) to remove Nullability, otherwise the will remain unchanged, containing Nulls (the change applies to new rows, not existing rows).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application, your database scheme, your entities.

Comment: Really ?  Others have managed to provide a stock or best practice answer.